# Saving two sets of coordinates using event Click Handlers

Tags: javascript, parameters, addeventlistener, chess

**What I've done:** So I am creating a game of chess in Java Script, and I have an 8 by 8 board (html table) with pieces on the board. I have currently set up some Click Handlers to recognize what board spot the user has clicked on (each td has its own id 0-63, and using this.cellIndex and .rowIndex I can get the coordinates).

**Problem:** My code so far is working but I'm currently trying to figure out how to save two separate user inputs (one selecting the coordinates of the where the piece currently is, and the second where the user wants the piece to go). My idea was to pass the variable cellContent as a parameter from "selectPiece()" to "movePiece()" so that I could have both variables in the same funciton but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions or other ideas?

**My Code:**

```
function addClickHandlers() {
        var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i< cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].onclick = function selectPiece() {
            var coordinates = document.getElementById("coordinates");
            var col = this.cellIndex
            var row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
            var thisCell = this.id;
            var cellContent = document.getElementById(thisCell).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var i = 0; i< cells.length; i++) {
                cells[i].onclick = function movePiece() {
                    var coordinates = document.getElementById("coordinates");
                    var col = this.cellIndex
                    console.log(this.cellIndex);
                    var row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
                    console.log(this.id);
                    var thisCell = this.id;
                    var cellContent = document.getElementById(thisCell).innerHTML;
                    console.log(cellContent);
                    document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    };
            }
            var postCoordinates = document.createTextNode("You clicked on coordinates: (" + row + "," + col + ").");
            coordinates.appendChild(postCoordinates);
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            coordinates.appendChild(br);
        };
    }
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
function showBoard() {
 var tr;
 var td;
 var check;
 var i = 0;
 var j = 0;
 var cellId = 0;
 var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  tr = table.insertRow(i);
  for(j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
   td = tr.insertCell(j);
   if(i%2 == 1)
   {
    if(j%2 == 1)
    {
     td.setAttribute("class", "black");
    }
    else
    {
     td.setAttribute("class", "white");
    }
   }
   else
   {
    if(j%2 == 1)
    {
     td.setAttribute("class", "white");
    }
    else
    {
    td.setAttribute("class", "black");
    }
   }
   cellId = (i * 8) + j;
   td.setAttribute("id", cellId);
   var content = getSquare(i, j);
   if (content == "br") {
   var blackRook = document.createElement("IMG");
       blackRook.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-black-rook.png");
   td.appendChild(blackRook);
   }
   else if (content == "bk") {
   var blackKnight = document.createElement("IMG");
       blackKnight.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-black-knight.png");
   td.appendChild(blackKnight);
   }
   else if (content == "bb") {
   var blackBishop = document.createElement("IMG");
       blackBishop.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-black-bishop.png");
   td.appendChild(blackBishop);
   }
   else if (content == "bK") {
   var blackKing = document.createElement("IMG");
       blackKing.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-black-king.png");
   td.appendChild(blackKing);
   }
   else if (content == "bQ") {
   var blackQueen = document.createElement("IMG");
       blackQueen.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-black-queen.png");
   td.appendChild(blackQueen);
   }
   else if (content == "bp") {
   var blackPawn = document.createElement("IMG");
       blackPawn.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-black-pawn.png");
   td.appendChild(blackPawn);
   }
   else if (content == "wr") {
   var whiteRook = document.createElement("IMG");
       whiteRook.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-white-rook.png");
   td.appendChild(whiteRook);
   }
   else if (content == "wk") {
   var whiteKnight = document.createElement("IMG");
       whiteKnight.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-white-knight.png");
   td.appendChild(whiteKnight);
   }
   else if (content == "wb") {
   var whiteBishop = document.createElement("IMG");
       whiteBishop.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-white-bishop.png");
   td.appendChild(whiteBishop);
   }
   else if (content == "wK") {
   var whiteKing = document.createElement("IMG");
       whiteKing.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-white-king.png");
   td.appendChild(whiteKing);
   }
   else if (content == "wQ") {
   var whiteQueen = document.createElement("IMG");
       whiteQueen.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-white-queen.png");
   whiteQueen.setAttribute("id", "botImg");
   
   td.appendChild(whiteQueen);
   }
   else if (content == "wp") {
   var whitePawn = document.createElement("IMG");
       whitePawn.setAttribute("src", "chess-piece-white-pawn.png");
   td.appendChild(whitePawn);
   }  
  }
 }
 addClickHandlers();
}

function addClickHandlers() {
     var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
     for (var i = 0; i< cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].onclick = function selectPiece() {
   var coordinates = document.getElementById("coordinates");
   var col = this.cellIndex
   console.log(this.cellIndex);
   var row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
   console.log(this.id);
   var thisCell = this.id;
   var cellContent = document.getElementById(thisCell).innerHTML;
   console.log(cellContent);
   document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
   var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
   for (var i = 0; i< cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].onclick = function movePiece() {
     var coordinates = document.getElementById("coordinates");
     var col = this.cellIndex
     console.log(this.cellIndex);
     var row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
     console.log(this.id);
     var thisCell = this.id;
     var cellContent = document.getElementById(thisCell).innerHTML;
     console.log(cellContent);
     document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
     };
   }
   var postCoordinates = document.createTextNode("You clicked on coordinates: (" + row + "," + col + ").");
   coordinates.appendChild(postCoordinates);
   var br = document.createElement("br");
   coordinates.appendChild(br);
  };
    }
}

//Game state variables

var grid = [[ "br", "bk", "bb", "bK", "bQ", "bb", "bk", "br" ],
     [ "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp" ],
     [ "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  " ],
     [ "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  " ],
     [ "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  " ],
     [ "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  " ],
     [ "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp" ],
     [ "wr", "wk", "wb", "wK", "wQ", "wb", "wk", "wr" ]];
var turn = 7;
var capturedWhite = [];
var capturedBlack = ["bp"];
var gameOver = false;

//Game state functions

function getSquare(row, col) {
 return grid[row][col];
}

function pawnMove(start, finish)
{
 
}
```

```css
table {
 background-color: black;
}

td.white {
 height: 65px;
 width: 65px;
 background-color: white;
}

td.black {
 height: 65px;
 width: 65px;
 background-color: black;
 hover {
  background-color: white;
 }
}

img {
 height: 45px;
 width: 45px;
 padding: 10px;
}

td:hover {
 background-color: blue;
}

body {background: #cba;}
#botDiv {position: relative; bottom: 0; left: 0; height: 65;}
#botImg {position: relative; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Game Grid</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameGridStyle.css">
</head>
<body onload="showBoard();">
<div id="botDiv">
</div>
<script src = "genTable.js"></script>
<script src = "model.js"></script>
<script src = "queenBot.js"></script>
<script src = "loadGame.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">  
</table>
<p id="coordinates">
</p>
<label>Here is your user data: </label>
<div id="username"></div><br>
<div id="timestamp"></div>

<button id="logoutButton" onclick="logout()">Log-out</button><br><hr>
<div id="loadDataDiv"></div>
<button id="loadGame" onclick="loadData()">Load Game</button><br><hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will help if you can edit your question and create a working snippet using `<>` from the toolbar to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I added the code snippet, thanks for the advice